# High CPU Usage when generating PDFs in Rails with Wicked_PDF gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, ruby-on-rails-4.2, wicked-pdf

I'm trying to generate a PDF file with Rails, but when I do I notice my system CPU starts to max out.  Initially, it will go from ~2.5% then increase to ~65%-$80% for a steady period of time and then finally max out almost prior to displaying them PDF in my iframe on my page.  Here are some messages I get when monitoring the memory usage on my system:

```
Warning or critical alerts (lasts 9 entries)
                          2017-06-09 14:58:07 (0:00:04) - CRITICAL on CPU_SYSTEM (100.0)
                          2017-06-09 14:58:04 (0:00:13) - CRITICAL on CPU_USER (Min:72.8 Mean:83.3 Max:93.7)
                          2017-06-09 14:47:39 (0:00:06) - CRITICAL on CPU_USER (93.0)
                          2017-06-09 14:47:29 (0:00:04) - WARNING on CPU_SYSTEM (74.7)
                          2017-06-09 14:36:48 (0:00:04) - CRITICAL on CPU_SYSTEM (100.0)
                          2017-06-09 14:36:45 (0:00:10) - CRITICAL on CPU_IOWAIT (Min:78.6 Mean:85.7 Max:97.4)
                          2017-06-09 14:18:06 (0:00:04) - CRITICAL on CPU_SYSTEM (94.3)
                          2017-06-09 14:18:06 (0:00:07) - CRITICAL on CPU_USER (91.0)
2017-06-09 15:01:14       2017-06-09 14:17:44 (0:00:04) - WARNING on CPU_SYSTEM (73.8)
```

The gems I have installed for my PDF generation are `wicked_pdf (1.0.6)` and `wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge (0.12.4.0)`.  And the process with code for each are as follows:

**controllers/concerns/pdf_player_reports.rb**

```
def director_report_pdf
  @players = Player.where(id: params["player_ids"]

  respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf do
    render pdf: "#{params['pdf_title']}",
      template: 'players/director_summary_report.pdf.erb',
        layout: 'print',
        show_as_html: params.key?('debug'),
        window_status: 'Loading...',
        disable_internal_links: true,
        disable_external_links: true,
        dpi: 75,
        disable_javascript: true,
        :margin => {:top => 7, :bottom  => 7, :left => 6, :right => 0},
        encoding: 'utf8'
  end
end
```

**players/director_summary_report.pdf.erb**

```
<div class="document" style="margin-top: -63px;">
  <% @players.each do |player| %>
     <% reports = player.reports.order(created_at: :desc) %>
     <% if player.is_college_player? %>
       <%= render partial: 'college_director_report.html.erb', player: player %>
     <% else %>
       <%= render partial: 'pro_director_report.html.erb', player: player %>
     <% end %>
     <%= "<div class='page-break'></div>".html_safe %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**college_director_report.html.erb**

```
<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
<%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<% provide(:title, "#{player.football_name}") %>
<% self.formats = [:html, :pdf, :css, :coffee, :scss] %>

<style>
    thead { display: table-row-group; page-break-inside: avoid }
    tfoot { display: table-row-group; }
    /*thead:before, thead:after { display: none; }*/
    table { page-break-inside: avoid; }
    tr { page-break-inside: avoid; }
    .page-break {
        display:block; clear:both; page-break-after:always;
    }
    .keep-together { page-break-before: always !important; }
    .table-striped>tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td,
    tr.found{
        background-color:#e2e0e0 !important;
    }
</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <span>DIRECTOR SUMMARY</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">
        <%= "#{player.full_name} / #{player.school.short_name}".upcase %>
        <h1><%= "#{player.full_name(true)} (#{player.school.code})".upcase %></h1>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <%= render 'directors_report_player_header', player: player %>
    <%= render 'directors_report_workouts', player: player %>
    <%= render 'directors_report_grades', player: player %>
    <%= render 'legacy_directors_report_contacts', player: player %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**directors_report_player_header.html.erb**

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>School</th>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Position</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><%= player.full_name(true) %></td>
            <td><%= player.school.short_name %></td>
            <td><%= player.jersey %></td>
            <td><%= player.position.abbreviation %></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**UPDATE**

I ran an example PDF generator using the following and the CPU% is what ends up maxing out as shown below...

[image]

```
 <table class="table table-condensed">
    <thead>
      <th>Number</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% (1..60000).each do |number| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= number %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Where are you hosting?

Comment: @jvillian, I'm hosting on an internal Ubuntu server 14.04 LTS server with 1CPU, 16GB, but I get the same results on my local machine which is running the latest Ubuntu Desktop version with 8GB

Comment: In my case, I was fine on local but had a memory runaway on Heroku. The culprit was wkhtmltopdf-binary. I switched to wkhtmltopdf-heroku and it all straightened out. Maybe look into it?

Comment: What is your question? Generating pdf or image is slow and cost some cpu time. If you can use html, then use html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting this in a controller seems ill-advised because the minute you deploy this the request will take a significant time to generate and block other incoming requests for other pages.

You should separate this into two concerns. One job that generates the HTML, which could be this controller, and then a background task to convert that HTML into PDF format.

In your controller, trigger a job using DelayedJob or similar and then render a page that polls for the job having completed.

Then in your background job you're dealing with just the task of rendering the HTML to PDF, rather than being within a web request. Something along these lines:

```
class RendersReportPdf
  def self.call player_ids
    html = ReportsController.render :director_report_pdf, assigns: { players: Player.where(id: player_ids }
    pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string html    
    temp = Tempfile.new("#{Time.now.to_i}.pdf")
    temp.write(pdf)
    temp.close
    temp.path
    # Probably upload this to S3 or similar at this point
    # Notify the user that it's now available somehow
  end
end
```

If you do this, then you can rule out that the issue is with running WickedPDF from within your controller action, but also you're making sure your site will stay up if you have long-running requests.

Comment: thanks! Sorry for the delay in getting back to you on this.  So you're saying I should create two different concern files: (1) for generating the HTML, (2) for generating the HTML to PDF. And then execute an Active Job that will perform the two in sequence?

Comment: My turn to apologise - short holiday! Yes, I think that wrapping all this up together in one is going to cause you trouble as soon as you deploy it. Better to separate these out and then at you can also see if it's causing things to lock up.

Answer (score 0):

So I wanted to post my solution for future visitors, but it's based off of @stef's solution - so thanks stef!

**controllers/concerns/players_controller.rb**

```
  def generate_report_pdf
    players = print_settings(params)
    pdf_title = "#{params['pdf_title']} - #{Time.now.strftime("%c")}"
    GeneratePdfJob.perform_later(players.pluck(:id), pdf_title, current_user.code, params["format"])
  end
```

**app/jobs/generate_pdf_job.rb**

```
  def perform(*args)

    player_ids  = args[0]
    pdf_title   = args[1]
    user_code   = args[2]
    report_type = args[3]

    generate_pdf_document(player_ids, pdf_title, user_code, report_type)

  end

  def generate_pdf_document(ids, pdf_title, user_code, report_type)

    # select the proper template by the report type specified
    case report_type
         when "Labels"
           html = ApplicationController.new.render_to_string(
             template: 'players/board_labels.pdf.erb',
               locals: { player_ids: ids },
               margin: { top: 6, bottom: 0, left: 32, right: 32 }
           )
         when "Reports"
           # ...
    end
  end

  def save_to_pdf(html, pdf_title, user_code)

    pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
                          html,
                          pdf: "#{pdf_title}",
                       layout: 'print',
       disable_internal_links: true,
       disable_external_links: true,
           disable_javascript: true,
                     encoding: 'utf-8'
      )

    pdf_name = "#{pdf_title}.pdf"
    pdf_dir = Rails.root.join('public','uploads','reports',"#{user_code}")
    pdf_path = Rails.root.join(pdf_dir,pdf_name)

    # create the folder if it doesn't exist
    FileUtils.mkdir_p(pdf_dir) unless File.directory?(pdf_dir)

    # create a new file
    File.open(pdf_path,'wb') do |file|
      file.binmode
      file << pdf.force_encoding("UTF-8")
    end

  end
```

With this way I then use an ajax call to keep checking the user's specified directory for new files, and I update the partial that lists out the files in the directory.  The only thing I don't like is now I have to have a table list of the user's files.  I'd rather just have the file get delivered to the client's browser for download instead - but have yet figured out how to get that to work.